# How to use line number with sed for replacing string

Tags: unix, sed

My file contains data like this:

```
A foo(a)
A foo(a)
B foo(b)
A foo(a)
B foo(b)
```

I want them to be converted to

```
A foo(a1)
A foo(a2)
B foo(b3)
A foo(a4)
B foo(b5)
```

At present, I think an approach to use IF with line number ($), and the sed the replace with sed. But, I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Some answers assume, that `)` is always the last character of the line.

Comment: @WalterA If ) is not the last character? Say, foo(a, 1, 2, 3). and I want foo(a1, 1, 2, 3).

Comment: When you want the linenumber at a different place, you must think how you can be sure that you have find the right position and adjust the command you need. Can a line be `foo(first),bar(nested(again(),difficult))`, can you insert before the first match of `[,)]` or after the first word after the first `(` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/\)$/$.)/' -- input
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing it
- `s///` works similarly as in sed
- `$.` is a special variable that contains the input line number

Sed could be combined with `nl` to get the line numbers:

```
nl input | sed -E 's/^ *([^ \t]+)\t(.*)\)/\2\1)/'
```

(Might not work, depends on actual implemetation of nl and sed, tweaking might be needed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try whith 2 sed

```
sed '=' infile | sed -E 'N;y/\n/ /;s/([0-9]*) ([^)]*)(.*)/\2\1\3/'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use `sed` only, you only get an ugly solution

```
sed = inputfile | sed -r 'N;s/\n/ /;s/([0-9]*) (.*)\)/\2\1)/'
```

When you use other tools for numbering, you get more possibilities.

When you want sed to do a lot of work, you can use

```
cat -n inputfile | sed -r 's/ *([0-9]*)\t(.*)\)/\2\1)/'
```

This still is hard to read, you will better of by stripping the last character and adding the number and `)` with

```
sed 's/.$//' inputfile | awk '{print $0 NR ")" }'
```

The last command can be replaced by a pure `awk` solution with

```
awk '{sub(/.$/,NR")")}1' inputfile
```